# SQL counting in columns inside cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is want to do is the following:

```
declare @Count numeric (10)
set @Count = 0
set @Count = (select count(*) from FILENAME where COLUMNNAME like '%e%')
print(@tel)
```

I want it do be done on a few files that have a lot of columns and have a total count for all the columns, so my idea was to get a columnlist of each file by doint something like:

```
select * from sys.columns 
where object_id = ( select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'FILENAME')
```

Now the easiest way i thought would be using a cursor and have the @Counts added up there in another variable. But the problem i am having is that when COLUMNNAME is in a variable in the cursor i can only (as far as i know) make the query like:

```
    declare @SQL varchar(max)
    set @SQL = @SQL + 'set @Count = (select count(*) from FILENAME where ' 
+ @columnname + ' like ''%e%'' )'

set @tot_Count = @tot_Count + @Count
```

But as I understand from reading around dynamic sql inside a cursor is a big no.
And though when i see the "print (sql)" the queries seem to be right it doesnt seem to work indeed in a cursos.

Is there another way to get the results i want?
Or am i doing something wrong here?

For reference, this was the idea i had in total:

```
DECLARE @columnname VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @tot_Count NUMERIC(10), @Count NUMERIC(10)
set @tot_Count = 0

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT name 
    from sys.columns 
        where object_id = ( select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'FILENAME' )

open MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @columnname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    declare @SQL varchar(max)
    set @SQL =''
    set @Count = 0
    set @SQL = @SQL + 'set @teller = (select count(*) from FILENAME where ' + @columnname + ' like ''%e%'' )'
    print (@SQL)
    exec (@SQL)

    set @tot_Count = @tot_Count + @Count

    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor into @name
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor 

print (@tot_teller)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Cursor is not good for tuning activity, I will post a query for your dynamic requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variant 1:** You can use dynamic variable instead of cursor operation.

```
declare @qry varchar(max)
select @qry = isnull(@qry + ' union all', '') + ' select count(*) cnt from ' + object_name(object_id) + ' where ' + name + ' like ''%e%'''
from sys.columns
where object_id = object_id('YourTableName')

set @qry = 'select sum(cnt) from (' + @qry + ') q'
print @qry
exec (@qry)
```

It's shorter, better, but exec is limited by 4000 chars.

**Variant 2:** Or you can use your cursor and via dynamic qry insert into your preprepared temp table.

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#tmptbl') is not null drop table #tmptbl
    create table #tmptbl (cnt int not null)

    declare @colqry varchar(800)
    declare mycursor cursor for  
        select 'insert into #tmptbl (cnt) select count(*) cnt from ' + object_name(object_id) + ' where ' + name + ' like ''%e%'''
        from sys.columns
        where object_id = object_id('YourTableName')

    open mycursor
    fetch next from mycursor into @colqry

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin

        print @colqry
        exec (@colqry)

        fetch next from mycursor into @colqry
    end
    close mycursor
    deallocate mycursor 

    select sum(cnt) from #tmptbl
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this was what i was looking for indeed

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @tot_Count int = 0
DECLARE @Separator varchar(1) = ','
DECLARE @Position INT = 1 
DECLARE @ColumnNameList varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(1000)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = ''

SET @ColumnNameList = STUFF(( SELECT name 
    from sys.columns 
        where object_id in ( select object_id from sys.objects where name = 'FILENAME' )  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+',' 

--print @FileNameList

 WHILE (CHARINDEX(@Separator,@ColumnNameList,@Position)!=0)
 BEGIN
 SET @ColumnName = SUBSTRING(@ColumnNameList,@Position,CHARINDEX(@Separator,@ColumnNameList,@Position)-@Position) 
 SET @SQL = @SQL + 'set @tot_Count = (select count(*) from FILENAME where ' + @ColumnName + ' like ''%e%'' )'
   -- print (@SQL)
 EXEC (@SQL)
 SET @tot_Count = @tot_Count + @tot_Count
 SET @Position = CHARINDEX(@Separator,@ColumnNameList,@Position)+1
 END

 PRINT (@tot_Count)
```

Comment: May have some minor errosr, not sure, please try and see if there has any error